# Why do I get a different result for the same calculation of a size of an array?

Tags: c, arrays, parameter-passing

Here you can find some code to verify by your own.

```
// a global variable
float array[10];

void countNumber(float array[])
{
    int number= sizeof(array)/sizeof(float);
    printf("NUMBER of array: %d\n", number);
}

int main()
{
    countNumber(array);
    // NOT CORRECT: Result is 2
    int number= sizeof(array)/sizeof(float);
    printf("NUMBER of array: %d\n", number);
    // CORRECT: Result is 10
}
```

I don´t understand why I get two different result (2 vs. 10 for the size of the array) but the calculations are the same.

Comment: You can't do that in C!  You *MUST* pass the size of the array (e.g. "10") as a *PARAMETER* to your function: `void countNumber(float array[], int size) {...}`

Comment: In the function, `array` is a pointer, not an array.

Comment: @Barmar: yes.  But the real source of the OP's confusion is that he thinks the callee will somehow "know" it's being passed a float array, and the size of that array.  In Java or C#: yes.  In C: no.  The link you cited is a good one :)

Comment: Of course, that's a common confusion. That's why I told him it's not true. The full details are at the duplicate question.